# Google Exoplayer How to change playing from assets/media.exolist.json

Tags: android, json, uri, datasource, exoplayer

Anyone knows this simple question as I am new to this?
How to change the default exoplayer that is loading Json from asset folder to remote (external) https json? example mydomainname/test.json?

here is the new exoplayer [Click here!!!](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

```
String[] uris;
if (dataUri != null) {
  uris = new String[] {dataUri};
} else {
  uris = new String[] {
      "asset:///media.exolist.json",
  };
}
SampleListLoader loaderTask = new SampleListLoader();
loaderTask.execute(uris);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

**Fixed**
This may benefit other beginners like me who couldn't figure it out.
The simple way I made this is by changing this line

> "asset:///media.exolist.json", to this "http://mysite/media.exolist.json",

and also on the DefaultDataSource file located in the Util folder to this

> if (dataSpec.uri.getPath().startsWith("/http:/")).

I hope this will help others too.